# super not working as I expected? (calling derived method instead of base method)

Tags: java, class, oop, super, derived-class

Let's say we have the following code:

```java
public class A {
    void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("Some method from A");
    }
    void someOtherMethod() {
        System.out.println("Some other method from A");
        this.someMethod();
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("Some method from B");
    }
    void test() {
        System.out.println("Test method from B");
        super.someOtherMethod();
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.test();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Test method from B
Some other method from A
Some method from B
```

Why in 'someOtherMethod()' from A, when we call 'this.someMethod()' the program calls the method from B. I was expecting it to call 'someMethod()' from A and print 'Some method from A' on the third line instead of 'Some method from B'. Why is this happening and how can I make it so it works as I intended?

Comment: This is how it is supposed to work, otherwise overriding methods wouldn't work, and you wouldn't get the benefits of polymorphism.

Comment: `this.someMethod()` means you want to call the method `someMethod()` of the current Object. The current object is a `B` and therefor it will call the method of that class. As already said this is exactly how it is supposed to work.

Comment: And how can I make it so that I call the methods from A?

Comment: Don't override it in B. Or make it either `static` or `private` to avoid polymorphism.

Comment: Move the implementation of `someMethod` into a private helper method. Have the base implementation of `someMethod` and `someOtherMethod` call your helper method.